# Count Over Date Range Instead of Count of One Specific Day

Tags: sql, date, count

I am trying to retrieve a count of alerts generated over a fiscal month instead of over just one day. My current code has me receiving the Total Count on a Day, but I want it to retrieve the Total Count over a Fiscal Month.

I have tried everything, what do I need to do to alter the code below?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT
    CASE
        WHEN substr(from_utc_timestamp(act.created, 'America/New_York'), 0, 10) = '[End date]'
            THEN act.activity_uid
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS Total_Generated_on_SLA_Date
FROM contactcentre.s_evt_act AS act
WHERE 
    (
        substr(from_utc_timestamp(act.created, 'America/New_York'), 0, 10) = '[End date]'
        OR substr(from_utc_timestamp(act.todo_actl_end_dt, 'America/New_York'), 0, 10) = '[End date]'
    )
    AND x_low_assgn_queue = 'Cust Care Exceptions'
    AND NOT todo_cd = 'Call';
```

Comment: Are you using Db2 ?

Comment: I am using MS Access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution with minimal change to the existing query.

You already have an aggregate query that truncates timestamp `act.created` to its day. Just extend the logic and truncate 3 more characters to get the month. Hence :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT
    CASE
        WHEN substr(from_utc_timestamp(act.created, 'America/New_York'), 0, 7) = '[End month]'
            THEN act.activity_uid
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS Total_Generated_on_SLA_Date
FROM contactcentre.s_evt_act AS act
WHERE 
    (
        substr(from_utc_timestamp(act.created, 'America/New_York'), 0, 7) = '[End date]'
        OR substr(from_utc_timestamp(act.todo_actl_end_dt, 'America/New_York'), 0, 7) = '[End month]'
    )
    AND x_low_assgn_queue = 'Cust Care Exceptions'
    AND NOT todo_cd = 'Call';
```

`[End month]` sould be given a value like `2019-01`.